# Keeping branches when changing from poly to mono repo

Tags: git, monorepo

I am changing 2 repos (old_repo_1 and old_repo_2) to a mono repo one (monoRepo) using something similar to this:

```
cd working_folder
git clone monoRepo_url
git clone old_repo_1_url
git clone old_repo_2_url
```

This is the folder structure after that (to make it easier to understand bellow):

```
working_folder
    - monoRepo
    - old_repo_1
    - old_repo_2
```

And this is the mono repo structure I need:

```
monoRepo
    repo_1
    repo_2
    .gitignore
    README.md
    ...
```

Continuing:

```
cd monoRepo
git checkout -b master
touch .gitignore      
git add -A
git commit -m "mono repo base"
git push
  
  
git checkout -b "mono-repo-branch"                                           

git remote add repo_1 ../old_repo_1
git fetch repo_1
git merge repo_1/master --allow-unrelated-histories
mkdir -p repo_1
for file in $(ls | grep -v 'repo_1'); do git mv $file repo_1; done;
```

after repeating the 5 above steps to the old_repo_2

```
git remote rm repo_1
git remote rm repo_2
git push
```

I can see I managed to keep both of the old repos git history, checkout any commits if I need to but the following command:

```
git branch -a
```

only shows the master and the mono-repo-branch branch.

How can I also copy all the branches and tags from the old repos?
Is that even possible without having multiple remotes?